# How to rotate a panned object about the center using three.js?

Tags: three.js

Using three.js is it possible to rotate a panned object about its center. I have created a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/yKt6h/4/

When I checked the Auto rotate mode in the control panel, i am able to rotate the panned cube about its center. Is it possible to have a similar effect when i try to rotate the cube with mouse movement.

If it is possible please provide me sample code

Comment: I am still waiting for a replay. Can someone explain what all modification i need to do in TrackballControls.js to implement this request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am getting an errors in the console when viewing your jsFiddle `THREE is not defined` However, what you are asking is not difficult. The trackball camera is designed to do exactly what you want it to. If you are rendering your object at the origin you just need to initialize the trackball controls. I created a simple [moon demo that uses TrackballControls](http://cmg0030.zxq.net/threejs/glslDemo/). You don't need to do any modifcation in TrackballControls.js.

In the above demo I call a function to initialize the trackball controls the function is defined in my ThreeUtil.js file as:

```
function initTrackball(camera, rotate, zoom, pan, damping) {
    var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
    controls.rotateSpeed = rotate || 1.0;
    controls.zoomSpeed = zoom || 1.2;
    controls.panSpeed = pan || 0.8;
    controls.noZoom = false;
    controls.noPan = false;
    controls.staticMoving = true;
    controls.dynamicDampingFactor = damping || 0.3;
    return controls;
}
```

If you don't want the user to be able to pan or zoom, only to be able to rotate around your object, then simply set `controls.noZoom = true` and `controls.noPan = true` in the function above.

Since my moon object is at the origin of my scene all I have to do is set the camera some distance away from the origin. We will put it on the positive z axis so it is already looking at our object at the origin. Then we call the above function to set up the controls. I pass in a custom rotation speed:

```
controls = initTrackball(camera, 0.8);
```

Then in each frame all you have to do is call the update function in your anim loop:

```
controls.update(camera);
```

Comment: i have updated the jsfiddle to fix the error. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/yKt6h/4/ here i have used the initTrackball code but its not working as expected. when i rotate the cube using mouse move its rotating w.r.t [0,0,0]. I want the cube to be rotated w.r.t the cube center. The expected result can be viewed when we checked the Rotate checkbox in the control panel on the Top right of the result page.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/yKt6h/5 does not provide a solution to the issue. I want the cube to be rotated w.r.t its center even after panning it. Is it possible to achieve that ?

Comment: You are not going to be able to do this easily with trackball controls. For the reason that we are not actually rotating the cube when using the controls. Instead the camera is rotated around the target. This gives the illusion that the cube is rotating when the background is solid. You would need to actually be rotating the object in response to mouse events. TrackballControls does not do this. Try looking at my [cube demo](http://cmg0030.zxq.net/threejs/acclDemo) for rotating (variable velocity) and [json model demo](http://cmg0030.zxq.net/threejs/jsonDemo) for moving objects around.